# Why does diff on these Pandas groupby results in Nan?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

The example dataframe I have is-

```
>>> new_df
        date country  score
0 2018-01-01      ch     50
1 2018-01-01      es    100
2 2018-01-01      us    150
3 2018-01-02      ch     10
4 2018-01-02      gb    100
5 2018-01-02      us    125
6 2018-01-03      us    160
```

Why does `new_df.groupby(["date", "country"]).diff()` produce Nan?

```
>>> new_df.groupby(["date", "country"]).diff()
   score
0    NaN
1    NaN
2    NaN
3    NaN
4    NaN
5    NaN
6    NaN
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see the size of each group is **1**,
then the subnetting of the subtraction is `NaN` because to make the subtraction a minuend and a subtraend are needed, that is to say **size at least equal to 2**:

```
df.groupby(['date','country']).size()

date        country
2018-01-01  ch         1
            es         1
            us         1
2018-01-02  ch         1
            gb         1
            us         1
2018-01-03  us         1
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Thanks. I did not think that way. Clearly, the documentation was not very helpful here. In this case then, first sorting and then grouping by "country" works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

It's because there is nothing to subtract--you have only one value per group in your example.